# Use Javascript Hash table for Multiple If Thens

Tags: javascript, hashtable

```
foo = document.getElementById("outer");

function cycleIt() {
    if (client.browser.Firefox) {
        foo.addEventListener("animationend", updateClassName, true);
    } else {
        foo.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", updateClassName, true);
    }
}

function updateClassName() {

    var z = foo.getAttribute("class");

    if ( z == "a" ) {
        foo.className = "b";
    } else if ( z == "b" ) {
        foo.className = "c"
    } else if ( z == "c" ) {
        foo.className = "d"
    } else {
        foo.className = "a"
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Someone told me on the Javascript Chat Channel I should make a hash table for the multiple if then statements. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would do is map `z` values to class names, like so:

```
function updateClassName() {
    foo.className = ({
        a: "b",
        b: "c",
        c: "d"
    })[foo.className] || "a";
    return foo;
}
```

The object literal is the map specifying what old value (key) should go to which new one (value). Additionally, it uses `|| "a"` to specify a default case.

Comment: Seems to me that the look-up object really should be cached.

Comment: @ChaosPandion How would I cache this look-up object?

Comment: In this case, do the old key values/new value act as if then statements? And what do the brackets [] actually do in [foo.classname]?

Answer (score 5):

You create the hash table (which is really just a plain object):

```
var table = {
    "a": "b",
    "b": "c",
    "c": "d"
};
```

And then you use the table to map your input `z` to the output (class name):

```
var z = foo.getAttribute("class");
foo.className = table[z] || "a";
return foo;
```

The syntax `table[z] || "a"` is a shorthand way to write

```
if (table[z] === undefined) {
    foo.className = "a";
}
else {
    foo.className = table[z];
}
```

The two styles are not entirely equivalent, but in this case (all the values in the hash are strings and none of them is the empty string) it works the same.

Comment: You don't need the quotes on the object labels... Right?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Not with these values, but it's a good habit to get a newbie into.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Member names of an object literal can take many forms including: `{ a:1 }`, `{ "a":1 }`, `{ 'a':1 }`, `{ 1:1 }`

Comment: Make sure you put that `undefined` in quotes, otherwise you're trying to see if the type is actually undefined, rather than having a type that is `"undefined"`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - Note I said "don't need", not "wrong to have". It was my understanding that in object literal notation, quotes on the labels is *strictly* "wrong", but Javascript is a forgiving beast.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - It is not wrong in any sense of the word. The syntax simply supports those forms because the designer thought it was a good idea. I suppose my point is that the syntax is flexible, not forgiving. Although maybe I'm reading your comment too literally?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: ...and because this is how you can write a literal with key names that are not legal identifiers.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - I could be confusing it with JSON. Nevertheless, I blame Felix Kling. `:P` Somebody on this site convinced me of that and he's convenient to blame.

Comment: @Jon - True. It's just not necessary *here*, but (according to MDN) perfectly legal.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Don't get me wrong, in my own code I never use quotes... *unless I have to*. But as a rule of thumb it's not bad.

Comment: True; I certainly didn't mean this to turn into a comment stream, but at least it's clearer in *my mind*.

Comment: @Jon - Oh boy I hate to nitpick but I can't help myself. Your original line `typeof table[z] === "undefined"` is actually the most robust form in most implementations because `undefined` is a mutable variable.